# Is there a most efficient way of structuring a Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am building an app using `Xamarin.Forms` to deploy to both Android and iOS devices, and it will have two released variants per platform. I created the solution and added two projects, `Test.Free` and `Test.Pro`, and both of those projects contain an Android and an iOS version of the app.

**This is how it looks on my computer, which I think is okay.**

[image: This is how it looks on my computer, which I think is okay.]

**This is how things look in Visual Studio on the Solution Explorer**

[image: This is how things look in Visual Studio on the Solution Explorer]

This troubles me, as the `Test.iOS` project is under the `Test.Free` project branch, while it should be under `Test`.

**These are the only two configurations I have currently.**

[image: These are the only two configurations I have currently.]

**The first one is what it looked like when I added the new projects.**

[image: The first one is what it looked like when I added the new projects.]

My goal was to have one version of the apps' code, and
construct the base app in that and have it added to `Test.Free` and `Test.Pro` versions of the app, then go and tailor each of those projects down the road once all the features they have in common have been added.

Why is `Test.iOS` under `Test.Free`? Is this the result of an `IDE` setting I have missed?

Comment: If I need to clarify further, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with answer from Daniel.

So, you should have one shared project, one Android and one iOS project.

Then, you can have multiple configurations like(Free or Pro or whatever you like to name it).
In your project settings, attach conditional compilation symbols like FREE or PRO and use them in code where you want to distinguish between your free and pro version.
Example:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{

#if FREE
            //do something
#elif PRO
            //require a license for example
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I should have used different configurations and just have one iOS project and one Android project and use conditional compile where the code is not the same.

And then I handle bundle names, version numbers, icons etc. in the CI pipeline.